# python virtualenv scipy import error undefined name

Tags: python, scipy, virtualenv

I just started using virtualenv for my existing python project and ran into some trouble...

When I try to import the following

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
```

it causes an import error if a virtualenv is activated

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
from .dsolve import *
File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
from .linsolve import *
File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 10, in <module>
from . import _superlu
ImportError: .../lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlu.so: undefined symbol: dtrsm_
```

When I use the global site-packages I don't get the error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: you probably have to install all packages your project requires into the virtual environment first.

Comment: Did you try using `--system-site-packages`?

Comment: I've already installed all packages my project requires, and I also get the error when I try to import this from IPython inside the virtualenv...

Comment: When I use the gobal site packages (using ´toggleglobalsitepackages´ from ´virtualenvwrapper´) the error is not gone. 
However, if I'm starting a new virtualenv using the --system-site-packages option everything works.

Comment: ... but then where's the point of even using virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's some sort of trouble between numpy-1.10.2 and scipy (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6115#issuecomment-172272208)). Try the following (it fixed it for me):

```
(ve) $ pip install numpy==1.10.1
(ve) $ pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scipy
(ve) $ python
>>> from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
```